# In GitHub Actions, can I return back a value to be used as a condition later?

Tags: github-actions

I'm setting up GitHub Actions as a CI for [one of my projects](https://github.com/mstum/Simplexcel/blob/master/.github/workflows/cibuild.yml), and the entire build process is basically a PowerShell script, driven by environment variables.

This is both to minimize vendor lock in, and to make sure I can run a build locally with pretty much the same process.

Now, my build script determines some stuff and puts it into environment variables - specifically, I have an `MH_IS_PROD_BUILD` variable that's either True or False, and determines which nuget package repository I push to.

However, when the step that runs the shell is done, the environment variable ceases to exist, as further steps are run in a new environment it seems.

What I *want* to do is something like this (abbreviated):

```
  steps:
    - name: Run build script
      id: pwshbuild
      shell: pwsh
      run: |
        cd scripts
        ./build.ps1
        # The above sets $Env:MH_IS_PROD_BUILD to either True or False
    - name: Push Publish to GPR (Dev Package)
      if: steps.pwshbuild.outputs.MH_IS_PROD_BUILD == 'False'
      shell: pwsh
      run: |
        # omitted: determine $nupkgPath
        nuget push $nupkgPath -Source "GPR" -SkipDuplicate
    - name: Push Publish to Nuget.org (Release Package)
      if: steps.pwshbuild.outputs.MH_IS_PROD_BUILD == 'True' 
      shell: pwsh
      run: |
        # omitted: determine $nupkgPath
        nuget push $nupkgPath -Source "NugetOrg" -SkipDuplicate
```

It appears that [outputs](https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs) is what I'd need, but that seems to require creation of a custom action?

The above does not work, of course (hence asking). So I'm wondering, what is the best way forward?

- Can I set the outputs of a step from PowerShell? (preferred)
- Do I have to create a custom action to encapsulate my call to build.ps1 so that I can return stuff via outputs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you can set outputs from Powershell by just echoing them to the console. Powershell has an alias mapping echo to `Write-Output`.

```
jobs:
  windows-test:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set outputs
        id: vars
        shell: pwsh
        run: echo "::set-output name=production::true"
      - name: Check outputs
        shell: pwsh
        run: echo ${{ steps.vars.outputs.production }}
```

ref: https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/development-tools-for-github-actions#set-an-output-parameter-set-output

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! [Works perfectly](https://github.com/mstum/Simplexcel/commit/55c88674d5aa8d1d9a1000932fd1c2127843a34d/checks?check_suite_id=293305023#step:3:186)

Comment: @peterevans, @Michael Stum I am setting ```$Env:MH_BUILD_OUTPUT = $buildNumber``` inside my ```.ps1``` script and trying to echo it from Github Actions. The code of Github Actions:  https://prnt.sc/t3isxb It echoes the empty ```$mhPath```. But after script execution it printed ```MH_BUILD_OUTPUT``` with the needed value. What do I miss?

Comment: 2021 Update:

Keep in mind, this "${{ steps.vars.outputs.production }}" returns a string and not a boolean, so when evaluating in a steps conditional, you should check for "a == 'true'" and not "a == true".

Comment: Is there an option to get the value that returns from the PS script itself (in above case: ./build.ps1)?
I mean, is there a way to send this output from within the ./build.ps1 script and use it in the workflow?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to answer by *peterevans*, you still can use environment variables for conditions, as long they are set via [::set-env](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) "command"

Example:

```yaml
- run:   |
         if [ -f FileMightNotExists.txt ]; then
            echo ::set-env name=HAVE_FILE::true
         fi
  shell: bash

- run: echo "I have file!"
  if:  env.HAVE_FILE == 'true'
```

As mentioned, there is **::set-output** already, so it's a matter of taste mostly.

What makes **::set-env** easier to use (in my opinion) is that you don't need to set `id` for steps (less typing), referencing vars is much shorter (less typing again), all variables you added will be listed for each step (folded inside `Run` block, can be useful when trying to find bugs in workflow), and well... it's just regular variable in the end, it might be easier to work with, depends on shell.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, env is also nice because it's available in the environment of every future step while output has to be explicitly passed into those steps - which makes them more "precise", but less automagic.

Comment: The `set-env` has been declared as deprecated: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/

Comment: You have to directly use `$GITHUB_ENV` now: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files `Note: Environment variables must be explicitly referenced using the env context in expression syntax or through use of the $GITHUB_ENV file directly; environment variables are not implicitly available in shell commands.`