# In a GitHub Action, can I extract a recurring variable or condition?

Tags: github-actions, code-duplication

I have a GitHub Action. In it I have several steps that should only be executed under certain conditions - in this case, these steps should be executed if the branch name matches a certain pattern. Like this:

```
- name: Deploy infrastructure
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' || startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/features/lrd')
```

This `if` block recurs several times in my Action. Is it possible to extract it to a shared variable, condition or function so I can get rid of the ugly code duplication? What would be the nicest way to do this?

I suppose that one option would be to compute the variable in an earlier step and reference it in the later steps, as explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58676568/4290962

It just seems a bit ugly to have a separate step to compute this value. Is it the best we can do? Or is there a nicer option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you use an **environment variable at the workflow level**, something like:

```
on:
  push:

env:
  BRANCH: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' || startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/features/lrd') }}

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check branch and print it
        if: ${{ env.BRANCH == 'true' }} # using directly {{ env.BRANCH }} might work as well
        run: echo ${{ env.BRANCH }}
```

Then, this variable could be used in **any job step**. I tested it here if you want to have a look:

- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/2495036527)
- [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester39.yml)

Note that you can't use the condition `if: ${{ env.BRANCH }}` at the job level, it's not supported yet. There is a reference [in this post](https://github.community/t/conditional-job-using-environment-variable/141995) on the Github community from Github Partner **brightran** about this specific point:

> About the [env context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context), you can only use it in the following scenarios:
>
> - the value of the with key;
> - the value of the step’s name key;
> - the value of the step’s env key;
> - in a step’s if conditional;
> - in the command lines of a run step.

Comment: Now I finally got around to trying it. It does not work for me in an "if" condition. The steps always get executed. It is probably because the environment variable get set to the STRING "true" or "false" (at least, when I echo the environment variable I get "true" or "false"). This does not work either: `if: ${{ env.BRANCH }} == true` or `if: ${{ env.BRANCH == 'true' }}` or `if: ${{ env.BRANCH == "true" }}`

Comment: That's strange. As you can see it worked on the workflow [file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester39.yml) and [run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/6879850191?check_suite_focus=true) I shared. Could you share what is different comparing to what I used there? Are you using the same runner and/or the same expression in the env variable?

Comment: I figured it out. There was a copy-paste error in my code. Still, your original suggestion of `if: ${{ env.BRANCH }}` does not work for me. That always executes the step. I need to do: `if: ${{ env.BRANCH == 'true' }}` in order to properly check the condition. If you edit your answer and include `if: ${{ env.BRANCH == 'true' }}` as a suggestion, then I will click the checkmark. :)

Comment: Ok. Good to know it doesn't always work 